# Removing gulp and starting over

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have an old project from two years ago that I am trying to update. At this point I want to remove gulp completely from my machine and start over with the new guide for version 4 of `npm install --global gulp-cli`, but I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /Users/danale/.npm-global/share/man/man1/gulp.1: ../../../lib/node_modules/gulp/gulp.1 symlink target is not controlled by npm /Users/danale/.npm-global/share/man/man1
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/danale/.npm-global/share/man/man1/gulp.1
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

I have tried `rm -rf node_modules/`, then `npm install gulp-cli -g` and the error returns. The file that needs to be deleted is here `0 lrwxr-xr-x    1 danale  admin       36 Aug 18  2017 gulp -> ../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js`.

I have tried `$ rm ~/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
rm: /Users/danale/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js: No such file or directory`.

I am still unable to remove it. How do I remove gulp completely from my Mac OSX and just start over according to current gulp documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it worked when I removed the file like so:

`rm /Users/danale/.npm-global/share/man/man1/gulp.1` and then tried:

```
$ npm install --global gulp-cli
/Users/danale/.npm-global/bin/gulp -> /Users/danale/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
+ gulp-cli@2.0.1
added 235 packages from 148 contributors in 3.038s
```